# I am using $scope.$apply to update an array of objects after an http call. Can anyone tell me the correct way of doing it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
method: 'post',
url :  appContext('ViewAllNotifications.json'),
data :  {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":$scope.allPageNumber.toString()}
}).success(function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        angular.forEach(data.notification,function(){
            $scope.notifications.push($(this));
        });
    });
}).error(function(a,b,c){
console.log(a,b,c);
});
```

I am not sure if forEach is the correct way of doing this. But basically I am doing an infinite scroll and each time the scroll bar has reached the bottom I am loading few more notifications and adding it to the $scope.notifications array.

Can anyone tell me what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: If you have declared `$scope.notifications` prior to your `$http`-call, you don't need to do `$scope.$apply` since everything is made "within angular"

Comment: I have tried without $scope.$apply as well. It just won't update. I reached a point where the array actually updates the value when I check the console logs. But it doesn't update on the view.

Comment: Please update your question with your html-markup where you're binding the notifications array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    $http({
    method: 'post',
    url :  appContext('ViewAllNotifications.json'),
    data :  {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":$scope.allPageNumber.toString()}
}).success(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data.notification,function(notification){
        $scope.notifications.push(notification);
    });
    $scope.$apply();
}).error(function(a,b,c){
    console.log(a,b,c);
});
```

You shouldn't really need to use apply actually, but try it out.

Comment: That is just as bad If your code throws an error angular will not catch it. If its used as part of a promise chain it will not reject the promise. Any exceptions thrown in the function passed to `$apply` will be caught by angular.

Comment: Dude... You're the man!! :) Thanks a lot. Can you tell me why do we use, and when don't we use $scope.$apply?

Comment: You usually need $apply when let's say you do something out of angularjs context.

Comment: @ste2425 - How would you suggest I go about it? This solution worked really, but if there is a better way, I would like to learn it :)

Comment: @user1504265 Well i don't understand, the approach in your OP should work just the same? The issue i have with this as i said is any exceptions won't be caught and forwarded on to any error handling you may have with angular. That may be fine but if your running promises it could cause issues. Oh and `.success` `.error` are deprecated and should not be used. Use `.then()` and `.catch()` instead.

Comment: Yes well we are a pretty big picture and we cannot update angular just yet. We are also using jquery 1.4.4 XD